What are the ways for the faster processing of raster stack
I have been trying to calculate the monthly means of 8day MODIS data and it is taking very long to calculate the mean. Is there a faster way to do this. I am using the following code to do it in R:
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)
library(raster)
# Set the number of cores to use for parallel processing
ncores <- parallel::detectCores() - 1  # Use all available cores except one
registerDoParallel(cores = ncores)

m<-stack()

foreach (month_name = month.name) %dopar% {
  print(month_name)
  # Subset layers corresponding to the current month
  month_layers <- s[[which(months(getZ(s)) == month_name)]]
  print(month_layers)
  # Calculate mean for the month (exclude NA values)
  month_mean <- mean(month_layers, na.rm = TRUE)
  print(month_mean)
  # Store the monthly mean in the list with the month name as the list element name
  m<-stack(m,month_mean)
}


I personally avoid to load data (the stack) in the main process as it need to be sent to workers for them to be able to work on. At the very least send subsets instead of subsetting in the parallelized loop. I prefer to load data in the loop and either return the result or save them in separate files to avoid overloading the memory.

I would do
library(terra)
x <- rast(files)
m <- tapp(x, "months", mean, cores=ncores)


Thank you. It worked like a charm. One thing I wanna add here. because I had the files as a raster stack and converting the stack to SpatRaster led to losing the dates. And I think that 'getZ' and 'setZ' synonym in terra is 'time'. Keeping that in mind, I had to add the following:
x<-rast(raster_stack)
time(x)<- date_vector #vector of dates
